# How to define a variable function and call it from an extension file in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, variables

I created an extension swift file, and in that file I wrote extension UIViewController{ ... } in my project, rather than writing all lines in every view controller. Everything worked ok. Later on I created a public func(i.e myFunc), with the **same name** inside each of the 30 view controllers, and having **different outputs**. I am trying to call this common named function from the extension file, but I get an error "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'myFunc'. On the extension file, how can I call this common named function which executes different outputs on each different view controller?

Extension file Code:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func sampleFunc {
        let viewController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController {
        ........
        viewController.myFunc() }.    *//error: Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'myFunc'*
    }
}
```

Note: I don't want to use like this:

```
if let viewController = self as? ViewController1 {viewController.myFunc()}
if let viewController = self as? ViewController2 {viewController.myFunc()}
if let ... 3,
4....30
```

Or maybe is there a way to check whether the function exists, and if it exists then execute command without receiving that kind of errors ?

> use of unresolved identifier

or

> value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'myFunc'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `viewController` variable in the extension is could be any VC, couldn't it? Not just the 30 you created. You can't guarantee that any random VC will have a method called `myFunc`, so you can't call it in the extension.

One way to resolve this problem is to create a protocol that your 30 VCs all implement:

```
protocol MyFuncable : UIViewController { // please come up with a better name
    func myFunc ()
}
```

This is an example of how you implement the protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyFuncable { 
    func myFunc() { 
        // do whatever you want...
        print("myFunc executed")
    }
}
```

Now we guarantee that everything that implements `myFuncable` will have a method called `myFunc`, so now in your extension, you can check whether the VCs are `MyFuncable`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func sampleFunc() {
        // here is where the checking happens:
        if let viewController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController as? MyFuncable {
            viewController.myFunc() 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Sweeper, I now tried it. The extension file recognized everything, but now there is another problem. I cannot call this sampleFunc() from my viewcontrollers (i.e error: Use of unresolved identifier 'SampleFunc'). The sampleFunc() should be called from all of the ViewControllers' "override func ViewDidAppear" sections, and myFunc() should be called from the extension swift file.

Comment: @AnthonSanthez Ah... I actually misunderstood the relationship between `sampleFunc` and `myFunc`. See the edit.

Comment: Hi again Sweeper. Now, sampleFunc() is available on the viewcontrollers, but the problem is myFunc() is not being executed. I just wrote print("func executed") inside it but it didn't output.

Comment: @AnthonSanthez Then there is something wrong with how you are calling it. You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, it just executed once but again didn't execute, what is the problem I couldn't solve. The functions are about checking web connection. In extension file, the code is the same as your suggestion. And in ViewController.swift file: class ViewController: UIViewController {     func myFunc() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
            self.button1.isEnabled = false
            print("function 1 executed")
//            self.Alert(Message: "")
        }}

Comment: @AnthonSanthez You didn't conform `ViewController` to `MyFuncable`, did you?

Comment: how to conform? I don't know how to do this

Comment: Now I tried Class ViewController: UIViewController, MyFuncable {....}                                         I think the problem is it doesn't see the current view controller as VisibleViewController, therefore doesn't execute the function myFunc(). Am I wrong? Maybe declare the if let viewcontroller = something else? I didn't think this would be so difficult to handle :(

Comment: @AnthonSanthez This is why I asked for a [mcve], and you didn't give me one... There is so much info that I don't know here? How are you calling `sampleFunc`? Is the current VC even embedded in a navigation controller? And most importantly, what exactly is `sampleFunc` supposed to do?

Comment: in this comment section I cannot edit nicely as it was on the post section. I will now answer your questions. Firstly, I am calling **sampleFunc()** in viewController.swift file inside **"override viewDidAppear{...}"** section. There is no problem in calling, and it executes the **sampleFunc()** from extension file. Secondly, the current VC which is also the initial view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, like all of the other view controllers.

Comment: Thirdly, sampleFunc() does the web connection activity. If there is internet, then it prints there is internet. If not, it prints no internet. There is no problem for the execution of sampleFunc(). Only problem is execution of the myFunc() which is embedded in sampleFunc() as written in my post and defined in the ViewController.swift file. Can I ask the current view controller which is open on the app screen is not the visible view controller? Maybe some issue about that?

Comment: now I checked by print something inside the if let viewController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController as? MyFuncable {
            viewController.myFunc() 
            print("inside") } else {print("outside")                                                                              and the output is "outside". The code isn't entering the visibleViewController section. How to execute this myFunc() for each of the viewcontrollers when opened on the app's screen? Is there any other way than visibleViewController method?

Comment: @AnthonSanthez I meant _how_ you called `sampleFunc()`. What VC did you call it on? Did you do `self.sampleFunc()`? `self.navigationController?.sampleFunc()`? Or what?

Comment: Hi again Sweeper. Thanks a lot, I solved it. Your suggestion was correct as AMIT's. The problem was that I was trying to solve that problem on a different project without a navigation controller than my original one with navigation controller. Sorry, it was my fault. That's why the function didn't work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func sampleFunc() {
        if let viewController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController {
            print("Class name: \(NSStringFromClass(type(of: viewController)))")
            let anyObject = viewController as AnyObject
            if anyObject.responds(to: #selector(anyObject.myFunc)) {
                anyObject.myFunc()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much AMIT! I tried your code also just now and it worked like a charm! With adding just 2 lines of your suggestion everything got great. You are really cool on this!

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer was wrong. Now I realized that the @object function myFunc() is not being executed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Print your class name with NSStringFromClass(type(of: viewController)) and check that class, where the existence of myFunc().

Comment: Sorry AMIT, I didn't understand your last suggestion, can you tell more detail? I am not so much experienced on that, only 2 months' experience:)

Comment: If any function contain in visibleViewController class, that would be called otherwise not. So checkout for which class it is not being fire. Identified that class and check has myFunc() exist that class or not. If not then myFunc() will not be executed. If yes will be executed.

Comment: now I checked by print something inside the if let viewController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController { print("inside") } else {print("outside")} and the output is "outside". The code isn't entering the visibleViewController section. How to execute this myFunc() for each of the viewcontrollers when opened on the app's screen? Is there any other way than visibleViewController method? Thanks for your attention and care AMIT

Comment: thanks a lot, AMIT. Your suggestion is also correct as Sweeper's. The problem was I was trying to solve that problem on a different project wihout a navigation controller than my original one with navigation controller. That's why the function didn't work. Thank you very much!